# How shall i define create sub-optional models in Optional[] working with typing and pydantic libs for FastAPI python?

Tags: python-3.x, model, option-type, fastapi, pydantic

Hi i'm a beginer in FastAPi, getting this error as

TypeError: typing.Union[pydantic.main.stats, NoneType] is not a generic class.

How shall i create sub-optional models?
these are my imports.

```
from typing import Optional,List
from pydantic import BaseModel, create_model
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: What is the goal of using `create_model` inside your classes? What are you trying to achieve that `Optional[StatsOptional]` doesn't do?

Comment: Remember to avoid posting code, data or error messages as images. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: I was trying to make the process-info as optional, but in the previous commit i used all these fields in one single create model, but i need to do distinguish that process_info field as sub-optional, thus was create_model at that time, now it is removed by using an optional[dict]. @MatsLindh

Comment: Will follow up the guidelines :) @HernánAlarcón

Comment: @AbhishekRatnam did you check my answer below?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just use an optional nested model, as described in the [doc](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/body-nested-models/#nested-models)

```
from typing import Optional, Set

from fastapi import FastAPI
from pydantic import BaseModel

app = FastAPI()


class Image(BaseModel):
    url: str
    name: str


class Item(BaseModel):
    name: str
    description: Optional[str] = None
    price: float
    tax: Optional[float] = None
    tags: Set[str] = []
    image: Optional[Image] = None


# do your stuff
```

Comment: very helpful, solved with this doc @floatingpurr